# Desactivar cookies hasta que el usuario acepte o no el uso de cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Debido a la nueva ley europea sobre cookies, el año pasado implemente en mi web el  tipico aviso para aceptar que sabes que la web guarda cookies y  que te lleva a terminos  y condiciones.

Ahora resulta, que segun una ley recien aprobada, la web no debe guardar ninguna cookie hasta el momento que el visitante acepte o decline el uso de cookies(incluido Analitycs). Y es aqui donde tengo problemas. No se como implementar el codigo, he conseguido [algo](https://www.metric.ai/blog/gdpr-cookies/), pero con esto lo que pasa es que la web, al entrar te guarda todo, y en el momento que declinas te borra todo menos analitycs.

Alguien me podria ayudar y sobre todo, informarme SI realmente esto se puede hacer?

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Podrias realizar un pequeño script al cual se envie cada vez que quieras iniciar una cookie el cual confirme si ya aceptaron o no tener las cookies de manera que le envies los valores de la cookies y el valor de si pusieron o no que querian dichas cookies. En caso de que quieran cookies asignar la cookie y en caso de que no simplemente no hacer nada o devolver una alerta para el usuario.

Comment: Yo acabo de darme cuenta que las unicas cookies que se guardan son de analitycs, y con eso debo trabajar

Comment: Podrias obligar que si desean utilizar el sitio web que te den el permiso de saber de donde ingresaron y asi poder usar tus analitycs , segun yo no deberia haber problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te paso algo mas simple de ejemplo http://cssdeck.com/labs/example-cookiecuttr . Saludos